# Run a function on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Just starting to learn HTML & Javascript. Managed to google how I can go to a url and get a value from returned JSONP, however, the function is running when I run the html page and I want to only run it from a button click.

I've googled on how to do this, but just adding a button tag and calling the function in the body is not working. I would appreciate if someone could help with some code.

I also appreciate that I should not be using document.write, but I think I can fix this once I have the button working.
****  Note I have removed some data from the URL as it has personal data in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title> Tesco JSONP </title>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function callMe(data){
        document.write(data.SessionKey)

        }

</script>


<script src="https://secure.techfortesco.com/groceryapi_b1/restservice.aspx?command=LOGIN&JSONP=callMe&email=xxxxxx@yahoo.co.uk&password=yyyyyyy&developerkey=zzzzzzzz&applicationkey=123456789"></script>



</head>

<body>


</body>


</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best wishes.

Comment: You need to provide more information than that it "is not working." Where is the code that you tried? You say you want to run the function when a button is clicked, but you didn't even post code that contains a button. As it is, your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's JSONP, the callback function is called once the script has loaded, so you can insert the script tag when the button is clicked, and the callback will be called etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Tesco JSONP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Click</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callMe(data) {
                document.write(data.SessionKey)
            }

            function clickHandler() {
                var script_elem = document.createElement('script'),
                    url = "https://secure.techfortesco.com/groceryapi_b1/restservice.aspx?command=LOGIN&JSONP=callMe&email=xxxxxx@yahoo.co.uk&password=yyyyyyy&developerkey=zzzzzzzz&applicationkey=123456789"
                script_elem.setAttribute('src', url);
                document.head.appendChild(script_elem);
            }

            document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. document.write did not return anything, but when I changed it to alert. I got back what I was expecting. Most of what you have written I will need to google as it is way past my existing learning. If you have more time, would you be able to elaborate on your code. I don't really understand how you are calling my original function callme(data).

Comment: The callMe function is the callback from the JSONP file you're getting, it's called automatically once the script has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from remote service you must do a request to the service url.
Firstly you can use jquery (I strongly recommend). Using jquery facilitates reaching your remote service with ajax. Ajax call is easy with jquery then javascript.. And then you will see the ajax request result as below.

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title> Tesco JSONP </title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function callMe(data){
        document.write(data.SessionKey)

        }

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#BtnShowMe').click(function(){

     $.ajax({
         url :'https://secure.techfortesco.com/groceryapi_b1/restservice.aspx?command=LOGIN&JSONP=callMe&email=xxxxxx@yahoo.co.uk&password=yyyyyyy&developerkey=zzzzzzzz&applicationkey=123456789',
        type :'GET',
        dataType :'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
           console.log(data); // chrome-firefox press F12 key, see console tab..
           alert(data.SessionKey);
           document.write(data.SessionKey);
        }
    });
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: when `JSONP` is used, it's not an `XMLHttpRequest` even if jQuery nicely wraps it in to it's `$.ajax` function to make it look like one.